# BlackBerry OpenCV Compiling New Versions

Tags: opencv, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-c++

I want to compile OpenCV v2.4.11 for a BB10 native app

What I tried:
Track 1: Using the already built android version of OpenCV 2.4.11. After solving all the dynamic links that I could i just had a couple of link errors with the kernel(found some headers in momentics that had a comment about not being implemented yet and some apologies ).
Erros:
undefined reference to `bsd_signal'

undefined reference to `pthread_getattr_np'

undefined reference to `setjmp'

Track 2: Compile OpenCV 2.4.11 for blackberry. I was not able to link against the ndk bundled in momentics.

Any help / knowledge / personal experience would be appreciated  !